# About runtime rendering

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to improve the graphic quality of the dynamically randomly generated house object.

Is there a real-time bake function provided by Unity? If that's not possible, is it possible to render just the scene from the camera? Like the way get images from blender rendering

[Before-and-after example assuming rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUWQN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to [High Definition Render Pipline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@16.0/manual/index.html). Then you will need to set up lights and all other settings. You can use Unity examples to get you started.